# How can I make use of dynamic properties with useState and Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In my application, I do get an API response with around 100 results which gets displayed via an array map. For every result, the user has to add some number. Now I'm working witch `useState` which needs an initial value. And I'm having an interface for the `useState` but don't know how to properly make use of the `setData` to add/update the values.

Any ideas are welcome :)

```
interface IData {
    [key: string]: number
}

const [data, setData] = useState<IData[]>([]);

function addData() {
    setData([...data, //how to add new/update]);
}
```

Comment: Sorry it is not at all clear what you are asking. You can do `setData([...data, newItem]);` to add `newItem` to your data. If you want to replace the data completely, you can just do `setData(newData);`. What else do you need to do that you need help with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
interface IData {
    [key: string]: number
}
const [data, setData] = useState<IData[]>([]);
function addData(el: IData) {
    setData([...data, el]);
}
```

Function `addData` is copying previous state with spread operator `...data` and adds new element on the end.

I put argument to this function `el: IData`, but also it can be taken from lexical scope. But in this way you can call `addData({a: 1})` and the element will be added to the state.

Comment: Thanks Maciej for you help. The problem i had was mostly with Typescript. But with some tweaks I got it to work now. Also I needed to replace the [] with {}.